# Chained Web service calls blocked

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm, reportingservices-2005

Here the chain of calls blocked:

Browser request -> CRM -> CRM plugin -> WebService_X -> SSRS

CRM and WebService_X are deployed in the same IIS. All calls are synchronous. SSRS is a service deployed outside IIS.

What happens is that WebService_X is called, but the call to SSRS blocks (no return from method call in WebService_X) until a timeout occurs between CRM plugin and WebService_X. As soon as the timeout occurs (default is 1 minute), the call to SSRS is unblocked (the method returns in WebService_X) and the report is generated.

The same call to SSRS from outside IIS is performed in 2 seconds.

Of course an error occurs in CRM plugin and the return value of WebService_X is not received.

What makes the call to SSRS blocked ?

Comment: Perhaps because WebService_X is running in a user context that does not have access to the network or to SSRS?  You can check this by *temporarily* confguring the web service to run under your user context.

Comment: When the timeout occurs, the call to SSRS is sent and a response is received. I guess there is pool mechanism or a protection somewhere in IIS.